# Removing negative values in pandas column keeping NaN

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I was wondering how I can remove rows which have a negative value but keep the NaNs. At the moment I am using:

```
DF = DF.ix[DF['RAF01Time'] >= 0]
```

But this removes the NaNs.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with another condition with [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isnull.html):

```
DF = DF[(DF['RAF01Time'] >= 0) | (DF['RAF01Time'].isnull())]
```

Sample:

```
DF = pd.DataFrame({'RAF01Time':[-1,2,3,np.nan]})
print (DF)
   RAF01Time
0       -1.0
1        2.0
2        3.0
3        NaN

DF = DF[(DF['RAF01Time'] >= 0) | (DF['RAF01Time'].isnull())]
print (DF)
   RAF01Time
1        2.0
2        3.0
3        NaN
```

Another solution with [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
DF = DF.query("~(RAF01Time < 0)")
print (DF)
   RAF01Time
1        2.0
2        3.0
3        NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `< 0` and then take the inverse of the condition.

```
DF = DF[~(DF['RAF01Time'] < 0)]
```